# Amazing!! Zipped file in android build apk cost more space then unzipped file

Tags: android, eclipse

Amazing!!  When I build an apk through Eclipse
a file zipped takes up 1.76M of space, while the same file unzipped takes up 5.56M of space.

If I put a zipped file in assets or res/raw the apk will take up 2.07M of space
If I put a unzipped file in the same path, then build the apk ,the file will take up 2.01M of space!!

Why?

Comment: do you think that zipping the file again and again always shrinks its size?

Comment: but ,It cost more space.that I don`t understand

Comment: because zipping the zipped file is useless

Comment: you mean that files in assets/raw will be zipped during the building process?how to avoid it?

Comment: the whole apk is a zip file

Comment: you`re right,thanks,but why cost more space

Comment: do you think that zipping the file again and again always shrinks its size?

Comment: Did you try to put it into assets?

Comment: Does the zip file contain duplicate entries that overwrite each other when unzipped?